# Samba Roaming not working

Tags: ubuntu, samba, domain-controller, samba4

I had configured Samba as domain controler on Ubuntu 14.04. I can register computers(WIndows 7) to the domain but the roaming profile does not work.

smb.conf looks like:

```
# Global parameters [global]
        workgroup = DOMAIN
        realm = DOMAIN.local
        netbios name = DOMAINSRV
        server role = active directory domain controller
        dns forwarder = 192.168.0.1
        allow dns updates = nonsecure and ksecure
        logon path = \\%N\%U\profile
        logon drive = H:
        logon home = \\%N\%U 
[netlogon]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/saray.local/scripts
        read only = No

[sysvol]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
        read only = No
```

What did i missed? There are some configurations that need to be done on workstations?

I have one user: User1 and 2 work stations: WorkStation1 and WorkStation2. I log in on WorkStation1, create a file on desktop logout and login on WorkStation2 with the same User1 and i expect that the file created on WorkStation1 to be loaded from server. If i understood correctly on logour user profile should be uploaded on server to the logon path = \%N\%U\profile. Even if i look on server i can not find the file created on WorkStation1 desktop

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific than "does not work".

Comment: I have one user: User1 and 2 work stations: WorkStation1 and WorkStation2. I log in on WorkStation1, create a file on desktop logout and login on WorkStation2 with the same User1 and i expect that the file created on WorkStation1 to be loaded from server. If i understood correctly on logour user profile should be uploaded on server to the  logon path = \\%N\%U\profile. Even if i look on server i can not find the file created on WorkStation1 desktop

Comment: Please edit your question and add those additional details.